# winbind and squid problem

Tags: squid, winbind

I've have squid configured with auth in the AD via winbind

now I have wired problems with authorisation

I found in the logs interesting string

```
 kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed: Cannot find KDC for requested realm
```

does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Most problems related to Kerberos authentication come down to DNS problems. It looks like your Squid machine isn't able to resolve the name of the KDC. Can you verify that you're able to resolve the name of the Active Directory domain controllers via their SRV records? (You *can* specify the KDC(s) in the /etc/krb5.conf file, but you really should be letting DNS do its job.)

Assuming DNS is working right, double-check the spelling of your Active Directoy domain name in your winbind configuration. The domain's name should be capitalized.

Comment: thanks,I'll do this

Could this be caused by missing Kerberos ticket ? 
klist shows error (and nothing)

Comment: It's missing the ticket due to the error in the configuration. fix the error, and rerun kinit, and all should be well with the world