# winbindd: kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm

Tags: samba, kerberos, winbind

While looking for reasons why [logging in to a samba machines joined to Active Directory is slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/585577/slow-first-login-to-a-ad-joined-samba-box) I have the strong impression that the following error in my log file could be a hint.

```
Apr  3 14:44:14 eu2 winbindd[19632]: [2014/04/03 14:44:14.166820,  0] ../source3/libads/sasl.c:994(ads_sasl_spnego_bind)
Apr  3 14:44:14 eu2 winbindd[19632]:   kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm
```

There are about 5 to 20 of these entries for each connection and I am trying to understand where the issue is. After days of searching the closest I can come with is [another SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/167035/winbind-and-squid-problem) which suggests possible DNS problems.

The facts:

1/ `kinit` worked and I got a ticket

```
root@eu2:~# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: yop@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04/03/2014 13:55:24  04/03/2014 23:55:24  krbtgt/DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 04/04/2014 13:55:19
```

2/ `/etc/krb.conf` is

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true
ticket_lifetime = 24h
forwardable = yes

[appdefaults]
pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
}
```

This configuration comes from the [Samba and Active Directory Wiki](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory#Setting_Up_Kerberos).

3/ I checked that the DNS is doing its work (to quote the wiki above):

```
root@eu2:~# host -t srv _kerberos._tcp.DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
_kerberos._tcp.DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM has SRV record 0 100 88 server1.etc.etc...
_kerberos._tcp.DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM has SRV record 0 100 88 server2.etc.etc...
(...)
```

4/ `winbind` version is `4.1.6-Debian`

5/ browsing the shares of the machine which require authenticated access is quick and does not generate error logs. Logging in does. Maybe this is a PAM issue?

Any idea what the error message in the logs can mean and what would be the typical root cause?

Answer (score 1):

Removing avahi-daemon fixes the issue on my machine.

I found the solutition here: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2013-January/171069.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you also check SRV entries in the _msdcs subdomain?

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/NetworkBrowsing.html#adsdnstech

Comment: I checked and there is a registration similar to the ones in point 3/ in my question: `_ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM has SRV record 0 100 389 someserver.example.com.`